# How can I change the text of a button which is in class element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My button is in class element. I want to change the value of "Go" to "Choose Location".

```
<div class="realContent" id="SearchLocation.find" value="Go">Go</div>
```

I am trying with

```
jQuery("#SearchLocation.find").attr('value', 'Choose Location');
```

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: provide code in OP.

Comment: div has no attribute named value use data-value instead. `<div class="realContent" id="SearchLocation.find" data-value="Go">Go</div>`

Comment: I am trying with 
jQuery("#SearchLocation.find").attr('value', 'Choose Location');

Comment: Use [edit] button to edit the question and add more information/code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this but this will change what is visible, content of div. Value attribute in div has no meaning.

```
 $('div.realContent').text('Choose Location');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
$('div.realContent').text('Choose Location');
```

Comment: Somehow it is working fine but the changes are reflecting on entire div id. Below is the entire div id.
<div id="divSearchLocation" class="divPaddedContent" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'btnFindStores')">

Comment: What do you mean? Please explain. this code with change the text of the div having class "realContent".

Comment: If you have more divs in your html with "realContent" class, It will change the text of all those divs. In that case, I would suggest you to find the div by ID. Currenly, Id of your div is "SearchLocation.find". Remove period (.) from this and use $('#SearchLocationfind').text('Choose Location');

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you want to change only attribute

```
 $(".realContent").attr('value','Choose Location')
```

Use this if you want to change  the attribute and text

```
$(".realContent").text("test").attr('value','Choose Location')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".realContent").attr("data-value","Choose Location")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="realContent" id="SearchLocation.find" data-value="Go">Go</div>
```

1. value is not a valid attr use `data-value` from `data-*` attribute.
2. use `.` as selector for class.
3. use `.attr()` to set the value

Comment: It is not changing the value of Go to Choose Location.

Comment: @Ishan check the div tools it is.. do you want to change the value or the text of the div itself they are different things div is not like input which has value attribute

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your button looks like this:

```
<div class="realContent" id="SearchLocation.find" value="Choose Location">Go</div>
```

Then create a jquery to change it's value as follows:

```
$('.realContent').attr('value','Another Location');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head><title>test</title></head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
<div class="realContent" id="SearchLocation.find" value="Go">Go</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".realContent").click(function() {
var $this = $(this);
var valueToChange = 'Choose Location';
  $this.attr('value',valueToChange);
  $this.html(valueToChange)
})
</script>
<style>
.sample {
  margin: 10px;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #4073ff;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't want the code to run on click... I want to change the text from "Go" to "Choose Location".

Comment: $(".realContent").html('Choose Location'); $(".realContent").attr('value','Choose Location'); Above code will help you, place is whenever you want to change the text